# Kotlin - filtering a list of objects by comparing to a list of properties

Tags: android, list, lambda, kotlin

I have a class Person:

```
class Person(var fullName: String, var nickname: String, var age: Int)
```

In my code, at some point I have a List of Person objects, and a list of nicknames.

```
var people: List<Person> = listOf(
  Person("Adam Asshat", "dontinviteme", 21),
  Person("Bob Bowyer", "bob", 37),
  Person("Emily Eden", "emily", 22)
)

var invitedToParty: List<String> = listOf("bob", "emily")
```

Now I want to get a List with only Bob and Emily by using lambda's, but I'm not sure how I'd go about it in Kotlin.

```
var invitedPeople: List<Person> = // a lambda that results in a list containing only Bob and Emily's objects
```

In C# I'd probably use LINQ and a .where()-method combined with an == any() but Kotlin doesn't seem to have anything like that from what I've found.

Is this even possible in Kotlin lambda's?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In C# you'd do:

```
people.Where(p => invitedToParty.Any(s => s == p.nickname));
```

Likewise in Kotlin, you'd use `filter` which is like `Where` and `any` speaks for it self:

```
people.filter { p -> invitedToParty.any { it == p.nickname } }
```

or using `contains`:

```
people.filter { invitedToParty.contains(it.nickname) }
```

Comment: Why not simply `people.filter { invitedToParty.contains(it.nickname) }`?

Comment: @Joffrey I guess one could do that as well. updated to accommodate your comment.

Comment: Thanks, in fact, I just realized there is more idiomatic in kotlin with the `in` operator: `people.filter { it.nickname in invitedToParty }`

Comment: @Joffrey agreed, there are definitely several ways to go about this, I just thought I'd show the `filter` + `any`  approach since that is the one OP is familiar with in C#. nevertheless, it's good to be suggested better solutions indeed. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Aomine and Joffrey. I'm always happy to learn multiple ways to accomplish something, I'll be trying this out as soon as I get back to my home laptop and then accept your answer.

Comment: `any` is the most flexible when `it` as the main object is not what you need but a parameter of `it` i.e. `it.nickname == p.nickname`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `.filter()` function to do this:

```
val invitedPeople: List<Person> = people.filter { it.nickname == "bob" || it.nickname == "emily" }
```

Or you can do this set-based:

```
val invitedPeople: List<Person> = people.filter { it.nickname in setOf("bob", "emily") }
```

Comment: Set-based seems most appropriate for my purposes; your first approach is hard-coded, which isn't what I need for my actual problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
val invitedPeople: List<Person> = people.filter { invitedToParty.contains(it.nickname) }
```