# how to get count of "collection set" from list having specific property

Tags: kotlin, collections

I want to get a count value of set from list having specific property
Thanks in advance

```
class User(val age = 0, val group = "school")

fun main(
    val list = listof(User(1, "school"), User(2, "school"), User(3, "company"))

    fun getCount() {
        //how to get 2 (the count of set such as ("school", "company").size)
    }
}
```

Comment: It took me 5 seconds to type in your problem into google and I got this -> https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/count.html . Do your research before asking here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you want to know how many groups you have (in your example 2: "school" and "company"

You could make a `Grouping`, eg:

```
data class User(val age: Int = 0, val group: String = "school")

fun main() {
    val list = listOf(User(1, "school"), User(2, "school"), User(3, "company"), User(16, "banana"))
    println(getCount(list))
    println(getCountOf(list,"banana"))
}

// returns the number of groups
fun getCount(list: List<User>): Int {
    val grouping = list.groupingBy { it.group }.eachCount()
    return grouping.keys.size
}

//returns the size of a given group (0 if group not found)
fun getCountOf(list: List<User>, group: String): Int {
    val grouping = list.groupingBy { it.group }.eachCount()
    return grouping[group] ?: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list to those with the group "school" and then count, maybe?

```
list .filter { p -> group ==  "school"  }
```

Comment: what is group and it ? it says "unresolved reference"

Comment: group is the attribute of your User class. Your list contains User objects, doesn't it? This lambda (which I'm adapting from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952047/kotlin-filtering-a-list-of-objects-by-comparing-to-a-list-of-properties ) should give you a list of Users with the group attribute "school". After that, you count the number of items in the list and it should give you the expected result.

Comment: it was a part of that original code that this case didn't need and I didn't notice earlier, sorry :(